# asp.net mvc 2, httpmodule routedata redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried to do redirect from w/i httpmodule. I have the following code in place, and hooked up in the httpModules section. This Error event is fired as expected, but this didn't go to the /Error/Index page.

```
public class MyHttpModule : IHttpModule {
    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {

        context.Error += delegate {
            var exception = context.Server.GetLastError();
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            context.Server.ClearError();

            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");

            IController errorController = new ErrorController();
            errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), routeData));
        };
    }
}
```

Please advice,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I created a new ASP.NET MVC 2 and ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

I added a new HttpModule and copy/pasted your code.

I registered the new HttpModule in the Web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="MyHttpModule" 
                 type="MvcApplication.MyHttpModule, MvcApplication" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I throw an exception in one of the action methods of my controller, e.g.:

```
throw new InvalidOperationException("An exception occured.");
```

Whenever an unhandled exception occurs I get redirected to the Error/Index page without a problem.

Have you correctly registered the HttpModule? I only get the described behavior if the module is not registered correctly. Keep in mind that for the Visual Studio Development Web Server (Cassini) and IIS 7.X you need to register the HttpModule in different sections of the Web.config.

For IIS 7.X please use:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add name="MyHttpModule" 
                 type="MvcApplication.MyHttpModule, MvcApplication" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I'm using Post, Redirect, and Get pattern. The problem is the EndRequest event throws an error for the Post. So, there is no chance for me to show the error page 'cause I redirect it another page. Not sure how should I handle this kind of situation. If I don't use ErrorController + RouteData and ues Response.Redirect("...") it will work. Very interesting!